# Wrong mix mode on textures

Tags: texturing

What is wrong on this graph, please.
Is it bug in Blender, or is it my fault?

[image]

Comment: This is not a simple math multiply (and this is not commutative operation) but a filter. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/color/mix.html. To do what I suppose you want, set the mix factor to 1.

Comment: What effect are you trying to achieve exactly? i have an idea but this won't really work mathematically in this case. Are trying to isolate the corner of the corner along the Z axis or have a gradient which starts black and ends white at the opposite corner? Perhaps the effect would be better done with maths nodes using the vectors.

Comment: I was trying to obtain simple multiplication of two textures for further experiments. Thanks @lemon, Mix factor must be st to full 1.

Answer (score 0):

As I supposed, it was my faulut, not blender bug. (Maybe blender's not-intuitivnes)
Thanks @lemon, Mix factor must be set to full 1.